# Best Practice - Variables in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've started a job at a new company and at my previous job I wrote a lot of 
Excel VBA code. At my previous job I almost never declared variables before assigning them. The exceptions were when I looped through an array using for each I usually declared x as a variant like so:

```
Sub sample()

Dim x As Variant

Dim myArray(1 To 100) As Variant

Range("A1").Select

For Each x In myArray

    ActiveCell.Value = x

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Next x

End Sub
```

The other exception I can think of is when looping through worksheets and declaring ws as a worksheet as below:

```
Sub sample2()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Tab.Color = 255 Then
        ws.Delete
    End If

Next ws

End Sub
```

But my new company declares all of their variables ahead of time (even the variable i in an i loop). What advantages are there to declaring ahead of time? Am I missing something? It seems to create more errors than it's worth.

Comment: Its a good thing to do for many reasons. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/declaringvariables.aspx

Comment: What reason did your employer give you when you asked them about it?

Comment: My boss just said it's cause it's what he learned in college. I always found that VBA was better at determining the type better than me. In the case of one block of code an error was being generated because a variable was declared as an integer and the number was greater than the limit for an integer and needed to be a double.

Comment: VBA may be better at determine what the type is, but it's not better at determining what the type should be. What if your code expects a date and you pass it a string? If you have 100% coverage on your testing you'd catch it. But saying you have 100% coverage is like saying you ship bug-free software.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring variables in advance:

1. allows you to specify the type
2. prevents bugs due to your subsequently misspelling a variable

The second point is the most important by orders of magnitude. Note that you can assert that all variables need to be declared by writing `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: I understand your points but isn't the second point remedied during testing?

Comment: Might be. But the best initial tester in the world is the *compiler*.

Comment: Regarding point 2, misspelling is nice but the debugging has more to do with not storing the wrong type of variable.

Comment: Also, regarding number 2, it seems to sometimes create bugs, since you can't test the type of input a user is sending and might simply get a type mismatch error vs. seeing what was entered and validating it.

Comment: Here is another benefit of declaring variables in advance: it allows you to get their names and properties/methods (in case of object variables) suggested automatically by Intellisense while writing the code.

Comment: `you can't test the type of input` but you can @tc_NYC